# Using command output in DOS

Tags: scripting, command-line, dos, command-prompt

I would like to run a command in DOS, which uses the output of another command as its part, something that single back-quote (``) allows to do on UNIX or Linux.

For example, if `myCommand` returns a list of files, I would like to execute in DOS some analog of the UNIX command

```
grep `myCommand`
```

How would one do that in DOS?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If by "DOS" one means "cmd.exe in Windows", then consider [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) as a modern alternative to that relic. Likewise, consider one of the several "Unix util" ports. FWIW, there are some *really old* program for MS-DOS as well, such as [Unix-like MS-DOS programs](http://garbo.uwasa.fi/pc/unix.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe two commands:

```
command1 | command2
```

But there aren't a whole lot of commands whos input/ouput plays well with each other.  You'd probably be best off using a for loop.  The basic syntax is:

```
for /f %A in ('command1') do command2 %A
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you try the for %%i in ... syntax, I do not see a hope in DOS. DOS is not Unix.

Another solution is to build a new batch using the for loop (with @ and echo) and start the new batch at the end.

You may need to do this recursively.